# flex 4.6 add or change element name when using addElement()

Tags: apache-flex, module, flex4, element, addeventlistener

flex 4.6

I am using addElement as below. I note however that when inspecting the element, the name of the element is suffixed with a number, so the loaded element name of `newMod` becomes `newMod10` (number is variable). If I want to then `removeElement()` I have no idea of what the correct `getChildByName()` would be, so `getChildByName("newMod")` fails.

So my Q's are

1. how do i addElement() with a unique name
2. how do find the name of the element I just added so I can reference by the nameXX

thx
Art

```
/*  load module */
/*   creationComplete="loadNewMod('modToLoad','A' )
public function loadNewMod(modName,evtTyp):void {
   info = ModuleManager.getModule(modName);
   var self:Object = this;
   var meh =  "modEventHandler"+(evtTyp);
       info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, function(e:ModuleEvent){
        self[meh](e)
            });
   info.load(null, null, null, moduleFactory);
   }

private function modEventHandlerA(e:ModuleEvent):void {
   vg1.addElement(info.factory.create() as IVisualElement);
  }


<s:Group id="vg1" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
    <s:Label id="newLabel" />
</s:Group>
```

[EDIT]
by breaking out the function I have added an ID that seems to work

```
private function modEventHandlerA(e:ModuleEvent,fcall):void {
   var newID = info.factory.create();
   newID.name = "myElem";
   vg1.addElement(hh as IVisualElement);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is likely to attach a name property to the object and do a for loop. It's inefficient, but the ID label doesn't seem to work properly when setting it in AS3.

```
info.name = "info1";


for ( var i:Number = 0; i < vg1.numElements; i++ ) {
     if ( ( vg1.getElementAt(i) as UIComponent).name == "info1" ) {
         vg1.removeElementAt(i);
         break;
     }
}
```

I didn't check to see if info would have the name property, but that would do the trick. Alternatively, you could use the exact same method with the id tag, except use indexOf("info1") >= 0, instead of .name == "info1"

Comment: thx for the feedback, you got me thinking if there is a more efficient way. the .name || .id etc does not work for `IModuleInfo` however I broke out the function above and this seems to work by adding an id to the .factory.create() thx art

Comment: You could always extend that class and add a name property yourself. Just create a new component based on whatever class the object is and add a public var or getter/setter to it. I know I did that with the Flex video player recently so that I could have some limited communication with items in the skin I created.